# jquery function not working while search filtering html select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have combined stackoverflow codes to made some code, in which html select option can be filtered by using a input textbox. Now, I am able to filter the options but when I am clicking on the option then jquery not working. I have setup alert when click on option. If without filtering the options we click then alert popup, But if we filter the options then alert don't work. Please help me, I am giving the code. Please don't duplicate it unless giving a working code. Please!!!

```html
<input type="text">
<select id="peaks" name="cars" size="5" style='border: 2px solid green;'>
 <option>Copper</option>
 <option>Silver</option>
 <option>Gold</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var select = this;
    var options = [];
    $(select).find('option').each(function() {
      options.push({
        value: $(this).val(),
        text: $(this).text()
      });
    });
    $(select).data('options', options);

    $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
      var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
      var search = $.trim($(this).val());
      var regex = new RegExp(search, "gi");

      $.each(options, function(i) {
        var option = options[i];
        if (option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
          $(select).append(
            $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
          );
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

$(function() {
  $('select').filterByText($('input'));
});

$('#peaks option:contains("Copper")').click(function(){
 alert('copper')
});
$('#peaks option:contains("Silver")').click(function(){
 alert('silver')
});
$('#peaks option:contains("Gold")').click(function(){
 alert('gold')
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: `.bind` is replaced by `.on` a long time ago and you need the change event of the select element

Comment: As far as I remember `option` do not support click handlers. Use `change` event on the `select`.

Comment: It's cause u rewrite your option and $('#peaks option:contains("Copper")') is execute one time then if you empty your list then your option contening Gold desappear, try with syntaxe like  $(".myclass").click( function() ... and you create 3 specific classes

Comment: Can you please give me full working code, please

Comment: I have tried these but it is not working sir